# Attack report on router log and slow internet. What's happening?

Tags: security, wireless-router

I have a new D-Link DIR 600L router sharing a PPPoE connection. After using several days, I am getting continuous IpSpoof, IcmpSmurf, UdpEchoChargen and some other attack report on router log. And I am facing difficulties while browsing. Sometimes, pages take forever to load. Please help. I don't understand these attacks and have no idea how to prevent this. I am uploading a fragment of my router log in http://pastebin.com/Xc9dH0Ya.

Comment: Are you connected to the router wirelessly?

Comment: Both wirelessly and with LAN. My desktop is connected by LAN and my laptop is connected by WiFi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are seeing poor throughput on Wireless, you might actually have a problem with QOS priority tagging with certain ISPs and router combinations which will absolutely kill wireless throughput (like timeouts and 9,000 baud style throughput).

Disabling QOS (or WMM) on the router will fix this, but this will drop it out of the "n spec" AFAIK, falling back to G speeds. Your router has "up to 150Mbit" wireless which implies to me that you have a 1x1 n and you probably won't ever see even 150 throughput with best case probably being more like 75, so the G fallback to 54 is probably not going to be much of a tradeoff.

See discussion regarding 1x1 vs 2x2 "n" see for instance ( [Laptop wireless networking options: 1x1 vs 2x2](https://superuser.com/questions/323347/laptop-wireless-networking-options-1x1-vs-2x2) ).

For discussion of possible interactions between ISPs and wireless n routers google `QOS wireless n comcast`.

Note that if I am correct, your intrusion logs are probably just something you can ignore: such wide random probing is fairly common. The logs indicate they are from the WAN side, and have been dropped/ignored (a good thing)