# Can I replace a 1x1 wifi card with a 2x2 card without replacing the 1x1 antenna?

Tags: wireless-networking, bluetooth

I bought a new Wi-Fi/Bluetooth card for my laptop. However once it arrived, I realized that my laptop has a 1x1 antenna and the new card is 2x2. If I'm not willing to swap out the antenna, will the new card still work, or will it just get slower Wi-Fi because the antenna type is wrong. Or will it not work at all?

Also, the new card is Bluetooth 5. The old card is not. Does the new card need a special antenna for Bluetooth 5 to work? My understanding is that the Bluetooth functionality is all on the card so this wouldn't be a problem. I'm not totally sure if that's correct though.

Thank you so much in advance for the help!

**Old card:** Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165

**New card:** Intel® Wi-Fi 6 AX200

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/323347/laptop-wireless-networking-options-1x1-vs-2x2

Answer (score 0):

You need both antenna wires for the zx2 card to work.

If what you have works for wireless, it may not work well. All you can do is try.

Bluetooth usually has an antenna in the laptop lid.

Can you instead get a direct replacement card?  eBay perhaps?

Alternately, try a compatible USB Wireless device with a driver for your computer.